# Wrong version of Watchman. Version found: 2021.09.06.00 Version supported: 4.x

Tags: watchman

After expo eject I run npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
It shows
✖ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

- Version found: 2021.09.06.00
- Version supported: 4.x
  I guess react native doesn't understand it because numeration after version 4.9 was changed. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with `doctor` - as you say, the date format ([CalVer](https://calver.org/)) versions are all newer than 4.9, [which was released in 2017](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/releases/tag/v4.9.0).

The misleading error was fixed in https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1700 (which should be included in new installations of RN ^0.70.1) - it can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm had the same issue after running 'react-native doctor'.

```
 ✖ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode
   - Version found: 2021.10.04.00
   - Version supported: 4.x
```

I entered 'e' to fix the error and it worked!

› Press e to try to fix errors.

Comment: But then it will go back on the next check, how to fix it once and for all?

Comment: Yeah... In the same situation here. Got happy when the error was gone, only to have it appear on the next session again..

Comment: 'e' in this case just opens the Watchman installation guide in your browser, it doesn't actually do anything. The warning can be ignored in any case.